# Close a c# form window after a few seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio, window

I am creating a very simple c# form in Visual studio. It needs to load, wait a few seconds, and close. I either need to find a hook after the entire form has been rendered where I can call a sleep method and then close, or I need a timer with a call back. I tried to use the form's shown event, but my one label had not yet been rendered.

Comment: How heavy is the rendering you are doing, is it just a basic form or are you loading an image?

Comment: Extremely simple: just one label.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096318/delay-application-close-best-practice

Comment: Just use a windows forms timer.  Start it in the Shown event. Stop it in the tick event then close your form. Set your interval to what ever you want your delay to be.